# Update row from future row (date and forein key)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
ID    Date        regNum   NumA      NumB
1     1/1/2017    85       NULL       12
2     1/1/2017    86       NULL       13
3     1/1/2017    87       NULL       14
4     1/2/2017    85       NULL       15
5     1/3/2017    87       NULL       16
6     1/3/2017    88       NULL       17
7     1/7/2017    85       NULL       18
8     1/7/2017    86       NULL       19
```

I want to update values `NumA` to be equal to `NumB` in the next `Date` for the same `regNum`.

Example : for `ID = 1` `NumA = 15`

**EDIT**

Most of the answears update only the first row, I want to update all the table !

Comment: is there more than one possible 'next date'?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Yes more than 1( or 0) sql-server 2008 r2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a cte to give the data rownumbers based on a partition of regNum and ordered by the date. then join the cte on itself to find "row_number +1" to get the next date's NumB column.

[db fiddle link](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=53a1dd1e7c48329c828885679ff18f6e)

```
;WITH RankedData 
AS(
SELECT
    RegNum,
    [Date],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY regNum ORDER BY [Date],ID) as GroupedRowNumber,
    NumB,
    ID
FROM
    MyTable)

UPDATE Base
SET
    NumA = Data2.NumB
FROM
    MyTable as Base
    INNER JOIN RankedData as Data1 ON
        Base.ID = Data1.ID
    INNER JOIN RankedData as Data2 ON
        Data1.RegNum = Data2.regNum AND
        Data1.GroupedRowNumber + 1 = Data2.GroupedRowNumber
```

Answer (score 1):

The real question is whether there are multiple "next" dates in your date.  It appears that there are in your data.

```
UPDATE MyTable t1
    SET NumA = (SELECT TOP 1 (NumB) 
                FROM MyTable t2
                WHERE t2.regNum = t1.regNum
                    AND t2.Date > t1.Date)
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM MyTable t2
       WHERE t2.regNum = t1.regNum
           AND t2.Date > t1.Date) > 0
```

Comment: I'm curious as to what didn't work, but it seems you already had an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can join it with itself and update affected records.

> ```
> update    t1
> set       NumA = t2.NumB
> from      mytable t1
> left join mytable t2
> on        t1.regNum = t2.regNum
> and       t2.[Date] = DATEADD(day,1,t1.[Date])
> where     t2.NumB is not null;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 1 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select * from mytable;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | Date                | regNum | NumA | NumB
> -: | :------------------ | -----: | ---: | ---:
>  1 | 01/01/2017 00:00:00 |     85 |   15 |   12
>  2 | 01/01/2017 00:00:00 |     86 | null |   13
>  3 | 01/01/2017 00:00:00 |     87 | null |   14
>  4 | 02/01/2017 00:00:00 |     85 | null |   15
>  5 | 03/01/2017 00:00:00 |     87 | null |   16
>  6 | 03/01/2017 00:00:00 |     88 | null |   17
>  7 | 07/01/2017 00:00:00 |     85 | null |   18
>  8 | 07/01/2017 00:00:00 |     86 | null |   19
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=a64a8c61140549416973b8cec2a5ef41)*